# How to increment a value appended to another value in a shell script

Tags: scripts

I have a shell script that executes a backup program and saves the output in a folder. I would like to update the name of the output folder every time the shell script run. In the end I want to have many files with different names like this:

```
innobackupex --user=root --password=@g@1n --database="open_cart" /var/backup/backup_1 --no-timestamp
```

And after running the shell script again:

```
innobackupex --user=root --password=@g@1n --database="open_cart" /var/backup/backup_2 --no-timestamp
```

Comment: use backup_ instead and check for existence of files starting at 1.  when you get to one that doesn't exist, use that...

Comment: Cool but why so difficult? Why not use a standard time stamp? Use `$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")` and you do not need to worry about iteration

Comment: @Rinzwind i think this will be much better as i will have different  folders each time thanks alot

Comment: Sorry but a timestamp makes it a different folder and you get to see when it was made ;) @Sitati

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the incremental value somewhere, for example in a log file

```
#!/bin/bash
FILENAME="logfile.txt"
NUM=`cat $FILENAME`
(( NUM++ ))
echo "INCREMENTAL NUM  : $NUM"
echo $NUM>$FILENAME
```

Comment: I have also tried this and it works fine

Comment: if it suites your needs please upvote the answer (and accept it if is also acceptable ;) ) @Sitati thanks in advance